# Equivalent of "teri lal," a Hindi phrase which means "you are right" said sarcastically (but not actually meant)

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, translation, proverb-requests

There is a saying in Hindi in India, "*teri lal*" which translates "yours is red". This means "Whatever the case may be you are right" as in "you are always right". It is a sarcastic way of telling (usually) a know-it-all person (but not meant genuinely) "you are right".

Is there an equivalent version of this phrase in English?

Example:

> **Rohan** (the know-it-all): The moon is a sphere
> **John**: hmmm
> **Rohan**: The moon has its own light.
> **John**: OK "teri lal" (you are right – sarcastically)

Comment: Good question. I feel like this is a perfectly commonplace situation, but I can’t think of a specific thing you’d be likely to use in English in this context. I think it would be more intonational; you might say something like, “Erm, yeah, sure… whatever you say”, but it would be the tone of voice that conveys the sarcasm. If you say the exact same words in a sprightly, cheerful voice, it would carry an entirely different meaning.

Comment: You could say ***noted***.

Comment: An English professor once told his class that there were numerous cases in English sentence construction where a "double negative" could mean a positive, but there was no case where a double positive could mean a negative.  To which one of his students replied, "Yeah, right."

Comment: Exact equivalents of all aspects of an idiom are usually very difficult. Does the Hindi phrase come from a longer story? Does 'red/lal' have connotations in other phrases that are related to this 'you are always right' idea?

Comment: “Yeah, right” feels like an open challenge.  “Wow! You are so smart.” ( said with whatever level of intonated sarcasm you like) can sometimes be slid past the recipient ) You can add a knowing wink to other listeners when you know they also know what an idiot the speaker is.

Comment: Some more detail would be appreciated. The sense I get is that the goal isn’t to challenge the speaker—say they are wrong and argue the point—but rather to accept their claim in a dismissive way that says you don’t really agree but also don’t want to argue about it. “Sure, we’ll pretend you’re right because it’s not worth anyone’s time arguing with you, you think you know everything.” If that’s the case, [alwayslearning’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/473807/24589) is by-far the best. But the question could be clearer about this, if I am getting the right impression.

Comment: Just to make it apparent, as to what is really [_red_](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSSIlllYl9npsHD91O3SOxVlyVTqZcndwF1LWXRgfg2OV1j2_26) in the context of the question. Thought about adding the image into the question at first, but I guess I'll leave that discretion to the OP.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena: :D :D I know what you mean.  It's hilarious to see novice discussion on something profane in Hindi.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena A big problem with online Q&A is people who don't know anything answering speculatively. Please add (in text; the image is secondary) what the closer to literal meaning of the Hindi phrase is in English. (I removed the mention of 'ass' because it didn't seem consistent with the rest and just didn't fit well in the English description. I see now it should be left in somehow)

Comment: @Rahul can you explain more of the details of what the phrase really refers to? This would help non-Indian native English speakers understand what is implied in the phrase.

Comment: @Mitch: What's implied by the phrase  is that _you are unique buffoon_ by sarcastically saying _teri laal_ which means _your a** is red_. It's a friendly gesture among friends and he gets it that he is being insulted.

Comment: @Rahul Is there a saying or story that involves a unique monkey (as in the picture) with a red butt? Or at least a longer proverb than just 'your butt is red' (something that makes explicit the idea of 'unqiueness')?

Comment: @Rahul Also, what do you think a good way to say it in English would be (that would capture as much of the original intention and connotation as possible)?

Comment: @Mitch I am not aware of any story but it's a local gesture of sarcastically pointing out that other person is a *unique monkey* hence the reference to *red butt*.  The way it involves an element of insult I would say *Oh yea, your shit smell sweeter than others.* ( taken from The Shawshank Redemption )

Comment: @Rahul haha I had forgotten that. That's a weird way to say it (I've never heard it that way except in the movie. The way it is normally said is "X thinks his shit don't stink", meaning he thinks he's better than everybody else. It may fit they say way for you but implies the other person thinks they are superior, which has little to do with saying 'you are _correct_ in your ideas' which is the implication of the title question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86081/discussion-between-rahul-and-mitch).

Comment: When uttered by somebody who normally enunciates "Yes" correctly or with a glottal stop replacing "s", "Yeah" on its own is a means of communicating doubt or disbelief. Indeed, the degree to which the "eah" is extended is a measure of the degree of doubt. Of course this implies fluency in English as spoken in a particular setting, and is pretty useless in print.

Comment: Important note from chat by @Rahul: "Yes it's very much in face and not used between not so known people. It's used between close friends who don't mind insults like this."

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Though I agree with the others that the sarcasm is usually implied in the *tone* of the speaker, there is an idiomatic expression which implies a non-committal agreement without sounding overly offensive: ***whatever you say***

TFD(idioms):

> **[whatever you say](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whatever+you+say)**
>
> I accept what you say, and I'm not going to argue with you.
>   *Usually
>   implies that one doesn't really agree with the other person*, but is
>   going to do it to avoid a conflict.
>
> A: "Don't worry about the auditors, just run the numbers like I told
>   you." B: "OK, whatever you say, boss."
>
> A: "I told you, my parents let me borrow the car whenever I want." B:
>   "Whatever you say."
>
> Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.

Comment: It’s worth noting that while this isn’t offensive, it is pretty rude and dismissive when done sarcastically. You are not avoiding conflict out of respect for the other person, but rather out of disrespect—you don’t think they’re worth correcting, or even capable of being corrected. Which seems to match *teri lal* quite perfectly, if I am getting the right impression.

Comment: This is often reduced just to the single word "Whatever!".  And yes, it's annoying.

Comment: cf. "If you say so..."

Comment: @Tashus, you should add it as an answer.

Comment: @KRyan: Sarcasm itself is pretty rude when done dismissively - regardless of the actual words used. What you say isn't wrong but it doesn't particularly apply to this answer more than any other answer.

Comment: I have found the tone of "As you say" seems to be a little less harsh to people than "whatever you say."  From years of using both phrases, I have found less adverse reactions to when I have used the latter, even if it is the same person.

Comment: @PaulBeverage That's an excellent observation IMHO - "as you say" doesn't imply you'd agree to *anything* they say, it just means you've given up arguing whatever point they've just made.   Since that changes the meaning somewhat I suppose someone more familiar with the connotations of "teri lal" would be the best judge of which is more appropriate.

Answer (score 37):

The most direct parallel might be the English expression "**[Yeah, right](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yeah%20right)**."

On the surface, it literally means, Yes, you are correct, but is universally accepted as meaning just the opposite, e.g., "*No way*," or "*As if.*"

Comment: It's also the punch line to a well known linguistics joke: https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/3a60z6/a_double_positive/

Comment: This is where I might just say "riiiiight", dragging out the "i" like that.

Comment: Sometimes framed as invitation to continue, "Do tell." This is a British form. Brits are more inclined to irony than sarcasm, and the inflection may be omitted to encourage the victim to continue making a fool of himself for the entertainment of others present.

Comment: Example worth watching (and entire movie in case you haven't seen it): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4iiGXoRoAg . Especially check the fragment from 2:20 and how Nick (the fox) answers Judy (the bunny) at 2:23.

Answer (score 13):

In English, just like in most languages, **the perception of sarcasm lies in inflexion**, modulation of intonation, rather than the words themselves.

One might say **"Oh, really?"** and intonation alone can make it a sarcastic remark or not.
Likewise, depending on context, several other remarks can be sarcastic and ironic.

- "How interesting!"
- "You don't say!"
- "You're so knowledgeable!"
- "X, you're here to educate us."

More about sarcasm in [**1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm) and [**2**](http://www.literarydevices.com/sarcasm/)

Comment: While sarcasm is all about tone, there is a phrase that comes to mind immediately in this situation, and none of these are it. The latter two I have never heard used that way, and sound weird to me.

Comment: Example worth watching (and entire movie in case you haven't seen it): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4iiGXoRoAg . Especially check the fragment from 2:20 and how Nick (the fox) answers Judy (the bunny) at 2:23. I know I put the same comment under two different answers but it does apply to both.

Answer (score 7):

There's a Scottish term for this. It's  **"Aye, right"**. It has to be said with a fair amount of sarcasm.

> When you have just said something to someone that they don’t quite believe, they are very likely to reply by saying – Aye, Right!! - https://scotlandwelcomesyou.com/scottish-sayings/

The joke goes that a teacher is explaining double negatives to her class and says that although two negatives make a positive, there are no examples where two positives make a negative. From the back of the classroom comes the phrase "Aye, right".

-- Just noticed Hot Licks' comment above. I guess it's not purely a Scottish thing!

Answer (score 5):

There's an old joke about an English teacher telling the class, “In English, a double negative is a positive. But a double positive is never negative!”

A student tells her, “*Yeah, yeah.*”

(Or @alwayslearning’s excellent answer.)

Answer (score 4):

If said with a sarcastic tone, a simple "Sure." is enough.

> [**Sure**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/194868?rskey=CMVezS&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)
>
> 2. colloq. (orig. N. Amer.). Used sarcastically to express scepticism or incredulity. Frequently in oh, sure, yeah, sure. Cf. right int. 1.

Comment: The longer you draw out that 'u' sound the more sarcastic it is. "Sure" is mildly dismissive. "Suuuuuure" is much more so.

Comment: Short breath, sigh, "Sure".  Or "Sure, why not", as if you were exposed to violently surrealist concepts but can accept another person's opinion with abject stoicism.

Answer (score 3):

***Indeed***, perhaps.

*Indeed* is used widely and idiomatically both interrogatively and as an interjection, expressing (according to the intonation) irony, contempt, amazement, incredulity, or the like (OED)

> *‘That's Jarsper's.’ ‘Indeed?’ said Mr. Datchery*.

Edwin Drood (Dickens, 1870) xviii. 141   (OED)

Comment: [Christopher Judge is a master of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tm8FwzHUGCs). He uses it in Stargate for just about every situation.

Comment: This is a very good answer to point out . This occurs in a lot of literature, especially  in the past, but still quite frequently in british literature, as it very succinctly  encapsulates exactly what OP is asking, and has the added benefit of not being overtly rude which is perfect for  the very dry, British,  one-eyebrow-raised-but-still-polite type of humour.

Comment: However, the word 'indeed', especially used by itself as a query is not used verbally much any more by those under 50 years old in my Australian English, (and USA English A.F.A.I.K) and sounds a little bit formal or 'posh', and likely, old fashioned. So I can imagine it's meaning and subtleties will become more and more puzzling to readers and learners of english as time goes on.

Comment: Yup, certainly seems that way - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indeed%3F&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cindeed%20%3F%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [alwayslearning's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/473807/251468), but in New Zealand English, the phrase "Yeah right" is strongly associated with a decades-long billboard marketing campaign by DB Breweries for their Tui brand. You should always assume it is intended sarcastically, regardless of tone.

[image: Tui ad: I'm going to study really hard this year. Yeah right.]

Answer (score 1):

"Yes, Socrates" works, and doesn't require any particular inflection or tone of voice to convey the sarcasm.

http://dailynous.com/2017/03/20/how-socratic-was-socrates/
"philosophers have been pushing this macho schtick from the beginning. Socrates is indeed their hero; if only they could do what he does, whether it be reducing their debating partners to silence or, even better, extracting succinct concessions to their intellectual superiority: “Yes, Socrates,” “You are quite right, Socrates,” “That is indeed true, Socrates,” “I dare say, Socrates,” and so on."

http://blogs.getty.edu/iris/a-non-philosophers-guide-to-plato/
"Thus there is a fair amount along the lines of: “Why yes, Socrates.” And, “It would seem so, Socrates,” and not much in the way of complaints about being unfairly backed into a corner."

Comment: You might be getting downvotes here for not having any references, which is a shame because this is a good answer to add to the list. "Did you know that the moon emits its own light?", "Sure it does, Einstein" sounds like perfectly normal casual English, and your point about not needing the particular sarcastic tone is very valid.

Comment: @ymbirtt I'm sure you're right about the downvotes.  I posted it on impulse, and references proved scarcer than I expected.  But I've added one.

"Yes, Socrates" doesn't work quite the same way as "Sure it does, Einstein."  Socrates isn't a generic genius, who's always right.  He's a person you just can't win an argument with (so don't bother trying).  Plato arranges that his opponents put up a token resistance, then meekly concede defeat.  At least that's the idea behind the idiom (if it is an idiom).

Comment: "Sure thing, Socrates", "smart thinking, Einstein" and "nice shot, Nimrod" are phrases which I'd certainly consider to be english idioms, in which someone insults a victim else by making a sarcastic comparison to someone famously good at whatever the victim failed to do. I think a good answer like yours would include a reference to this particular idiom, rather than vague information about who certain philosophers were. You might then mention a particular philosopher as being particularly apt for the "person who cannot ever be argued with" charicature once you've established the idiom.

Comment: Too late to edit, but "someone insults a victim else by" should read "someone insults a victim by"

Comment: @ymbirtt Both quoted passages not only indicate that Socrates is particularly apt for the "person who cannot ever be argued with" caricature;  they both also actually use the phrase "Yes, Socrates," and variants, in the indicated sense.

Comment: I think this would only apply if the person was asking a lot of questions instead of making statements. Because that was his style.

Answer (score 1):

My mother always says (sarcastically / indulgently)

**"*I'll* believe you, but thousands wouldn't"**.

(We're australian, UK ancestry, my mum is in her late 60s)
EDIT: Aha! It's not just my mum:

The following is from ["The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English" found on google books](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1213&lpg=PA1213&dq=%22i%27ll%20believe%20you%20but%20thousands%20wouldn%27t%22&source=bl&ots=PFwwsM-R8I&sig=tE5V5IrFDlQN2Oy9YseJUP3OSRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZx6HF7fDeAhWKuY8KHcHvCxcQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22i'll%20believe%20you%20but%20thousands%20wouldn't%22&f=false)

> **I believe you but thousands wouldn't**
>   - a catchphrase retort that is used to express doubt or, at best, reserve judgement about the veracity of the person being addressed.
>   - Quotation: "It's the God's honest truth I'm telling you, Johnny". Mellors stood frowning down at him for a moment, then he said,"All
>   right kid, I'll believe you but thousands wouldn't. Now sleep it off"
>   (Derek Bickerton, *Payroll* 1959)

The following is from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/I_believe_you,_thousands_wouldn%27t

> **I believe you, thousands wouldn't**
>
> 1. *(Britain, Ireland, sarcastic)* Used to indicate that the speaker does not put faith in something they have just heard.
>
>    - *Quotation:* 2004, Sandra Newman, *The Only Good Thing Anyone Has Ever Done: A Novel*, →ISBN, page 185: You weren't working on germ warfare
>        five years ago." "Non-lethal," she cries. "Oh, how you can not see."
>        "**Well, I believe you, thousands wouldn't** […]

Personal note:
I've always liked this phrase because it's kind of sweet how it doesn't accuse the person of speaking rubbish outright :)
In fact, my mum said this to a number of tall tales I relayed to her from classic works of literature such as "1001 crazy facts from around the world for kids", which although I now realise were more 'sensationalised-and-hard-to-disprove-historical/urban-myths', at the time, I was quite wounded by her implicit accusation, and would launch into a passionate defence of my source, yet I also felt a bit smug because, like the phase taken literally, *I* knew something which was quite obscure, and likely thousands *actually* wouldn't! :)

Answer (score 0):

My new favorite is

### You're not wrong

Which implies they may be technically correct but are still incorrect in spirit. Or put another way, it implies they may not be wrong, but they aren't necessarily right either.

I wouldn't say it's entirely sarcastic, but more of a funny quip.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=you%27re%20not%20wrong

> "you're not wrong" = "you're right", however phrasing it as "you're not wrong" usually that there's more to it -- either there's some missing nuance, or the speaker agrees grudgingly or doesn't like this truth or wishes it wasn't so, etc.
> Alice: Bob, you drink too much. 
> Bob: You're not wrong.

---

> Something someone says when they dispute what you're saying but does so in an underhanded way. It's often followed by a "but".

Comment: Not in Australia.  This is just our way of saying yes, possibly somewhat emphatically. "Jeez it's hot today." "You're not wrong there, mate."